# What are the correct steps to upgrade from the VS 11 Developer Preview to the VS 11 Beta?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

What are the correct steps to upgrade from the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview to the Visual Studio 11 Beta?

Is it possible to upgrade the current installation to Beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All download page in Microsoft will have related resources which includes suported platform, system requirements etc. Check the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads) which says.

Not supported:

1. Upgrade from Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview to Beta; however, you can install Visual Studio 11 Beta after uninstalling Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview
2. Upgrade from Visual Studio 11 Beta to Release (RTM)

Comment: That said, I did it. Some pointers to older apps (feedback tool etc) but all works fine, so far :)

Comment: Even though it shouldn't be possible, the Beta installer actually allowed it for me, messing up my VS11 Beta install. What happened? VS11 would crash on breakpoints. What to do? Uninstall both the Developer Preview and the Beta and then reinstall the beta.

Answer (score 1):

The *Upgrade Paths* section of the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads) says:

> **Not supported:**
>
> Upgrade from Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview to Beta; however,
>   you can install Visual Studio 11 Beta after uninstalling Visual Studio
>   11 Developer Preview

So, no.